# After first click, google-oauth screen does not show anymore?

Tags: node.js, typescript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

This is very odd behavior. Everytime i get a new credentials, I click on the link, I get the consent screen but after that consent screen does not show anymore but request to google server and and response to callback url is happening behind the scene. I logout user "/auth/logout", I also delete all the cookies stored manually, When I clieck on the button, I am automatically signed in again.

I belive there is nothing wrong with coding and I checked the consent screen of console.developers but there is nothing related to this issue.
[image]

this is a typescript project. here is the routes

```
import passport from "passport";
import { Application, Request, Response } from "express";

export const authRoutes = (app: Application) => {
  app.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
      scope: ["profile", "email"],
    })
  );

  app.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google"),
    (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  );

  // passport sees the code here and it knows that it has to use the code to get user
  app.get("/auth/current_user", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send(req.user);
  });
  app.get("/auth/logout", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    req.logout();
    res.json({ user: req.user });
  });
};
```

here is the passport setting:

```
import GoogleStrategy from "passport-google-oauth20";
import passport from "passport";
import { User, UserDoc } from "../database/models/User";

// passport sets up the cookie and stuffs the user's database id not the googleId.
passport.serializeUser(
  (user: UserDoc, done: (err: any, user: UserDoc) => void) => {
    done(null, user.id);
  }
);

passport.deserializeUser(
  async (id: string, done: (err: any, user: UserDoc) => void) => {
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    if (user) {
      done(null, user);
    }
  }
);

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy.Strategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:4500/auth/google/callback",
      proxy: true,
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });
      if (existingUser) {
        done(undefined, existingUser);
      }
      const user = await new User({ googleId: profile.id }).save();
      done(undefined, user);
    }
  )
);
```

Comment: did you try clearing cookies?

Comment: @DaImTo hi. yes i did. I visit the route "auth/logout" and I even deleted manually from chrome app tab, and click again it makes me automatically sign in again

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "automatically logged in again". Do you need to give the username? The password? Consent to permissions?

Comment: @Prisoner I clear the cookies, I go to "/auth/current_user", It is null.  Then i click on the signin button, i dont get the consent screen but it sill logs me in without consent screen. I visit the "auth/current_user" and i see the user

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is the desired behavior - once the user has granted authorization to the scopes you're asking for (that are shown in the consent screen), Google doesn't need to get the user's consent again. It keeps track of that.

Users can review and revoke access to your app (mobile or web-based) at https://myaccount.google.com/permissions. This is particularly useful during development so you don't have to constantly create new accounts to test with.

Comment: you can also make call to the revoke endpoint using an access token that would also remove the users permissions.

Comment: even after I logout, clear the cookies, I click on the button but still automatically logs in. is it also default behavior. (In fact I should have mentioned this)

Comment: Logging out is unrelated to removing permissions. Logging out just clears the current user, but leaves your app with the consented permissions. To revoke the permissions, you either need to access the page mentioned, or the revocation access point DalmTo mentions.

Comment: Just to add to this, you can add the `prompt: 'consent'` option to force the user to re-consent to the application.